# Mysql connector LNK2019 error

Tags: c++, mysql, connector

```
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall sql::SQLString::~SQLString(void)" (__imp_??1SQLString@sql@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function _main
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall sql::SQLString::SQLString(char const * const)" (__imp_??0SQLString@sql@@QAE@QBD@Z) referenced in function _main
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) class sql::mysql::MySQL_Driver * __cdecl sql::mysql::get_driver_instance(void)" (__imp_?   get_driver_instance@mysql@sql@@YAPAVMySQL_Driver@12@XZ) referenced in function "class   sql::mysql::MySQL_Driver * __cdecl sql::mysql::get_mysql_driver_instance(void)" (?  get_mysql_driver_instance@mysql@sql@@YAPAVMySQL_Driver@12@XZ)
1>C:\Users\Mantas\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\testsss\Debug\testsss.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 3 unresolved externals
```

I get these errors when using this code. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. If I just compile commenting driver and con lines it runs

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mysql_connection.h>
#include <mysql_driver.h>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    sql::mysql::MySQL_Driver *driver;
    sql::Connection *con;

    driver = sql::mysql::get_mysql_driver_instance();
    con = driver->connect("tcp://77.241.206.122", "mantas7776", "");

    char a;
    cin >> a;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Looks like you are not linking with your SQL library. This page may help, particularly steps 10, 11 and 12. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-cpp-apps-windows-visual-studio.html

Comment: i have already done these steps

Comment: Check that you aren't mixing 32 bit and 64 bit code. I.e. compiling for 64 bits but linking with a 32 bit library (or vice versa).

Comment: tried changing to 32 bit but still getting same error.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure what to suggest, maybe you just didn't follow the steps correctly.

Comment: Set incramental linking to "no". Now i get LNK2001.